# glsl vectorized data multiply

Tags: opengl, glsl

Would this (in GLSL vertex shader) be faster

```
 float f1, f2, f3, f4;
 float v1, v2, v3, v4;

 vec4 m = vec2(f1*v1, f2*v2, f3*v3, f4*v4);
```

Than this?

```
 float f1, f2, f3, f4;
 float v1, v2, v3, v4;
 float m1, m2, m3, m4;

 m1 = f1*v1;
 m2 = f2*v2;
 m3 = f3*v3;
 m4 = f4*v4;
```

---

UPDATED

And what about this case?

```
 vec4 m = vec2(f1/v1, f2*v2, f3+v3, f4-v4);
```

Answer (score 3):

With a descent compiler, the 2 codes should produce the same machine binary.
You should focus on readabiltity in this case. A simple code would look like:

```
vec4 f = vec4(f1, f2, f3, f4);
vec4 v = vec4(v1, v2, v3, v4);
vec4 m = f * v;
```

> And what about this case?

A descent compiler will probably leave the code as is for scalar (or scalar simd) units. It will try to find similar instructions and pack them together for VLIW, SSE style instructions. It may also look at other instructions and their dependencies then order instructions to improve caching, pipelining, out of order execution, parallel ALUs, use of instructions like MAD, FMA...
It really depends on the hardware and the compiler/optimizer behavior.
Often, the compiler wouldn't do what seems to be the right thing. Instead, it will try to reduce cache thrashing and register pressure allowing opportunities to hide latency.

Comment: descent compiler? I thought compiler is driver/system dependent :). For you case it will took additional cycles to form vec4, especially on old GPU. It is known that vec4*vec4 take 1 cycle. But is it true for per component operations? Look updated question.

Comment: vec4*vec4 latency/throughput depends on hardware and may result in one or multiple instructions. If vec4*vec4 is the good solution, a descent compiler in your driver/system will try to optimize products into vec4*vec4 operations. A simple readable code is what you should write. If you target a specific platform and you know how the hw/compiler behaves and if performance is critical for a piece of code then sacrificing code quality is not that unreasonable

Comment: I just compared squaring two separate floats like "float a *= a; float b *= b" vs "vec2 ab = vec2(a, b); ab *= ab;". The vectorized version was faster. GPU: Nvidia GTX 460